# defining a target when compiling a visual c++ project using xbuild

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I have a visual c++ project that outputs a library and I would like to build it on Linux using xmake. I can build it in monodevelop but I want to be able to build it from a command line.

If I try building the project using "xbuild" call then I get the following error:

```
....ItemMinerLibMono.cproj: error : Target named 'Build' not found in the project.
```

I understand from the documentation that I need to add a Target named "Build" in the csproj file but I don't know how to do that. I tried importing the Microsoft.Common.targets file like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
```

but then I get the error:

```
: error : Target 'CreateManifestResourceNames', a dependency of target 'PrepareResources', not found.
```

Does anybody have any idea how to successfully compile a c++ project from a command line?

Thanks,
Gregor

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to you .cproj file from MonoDevelop and it will build with xbuild.

```
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" Outputs="$(TargetPath)"/>
```

There is probably a simpler solution, but so far I have not been able to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Cpp targets.

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
```

On a Windows machine with a full Visual Studio installation, some or all of these can be found at the following locations. I've not tested these under any version of Linux with `xbuild`:

**VS2012**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v110`
**VS2013**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v120`
**VS2015**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140`

Comment: thanks for the answer. unfortunately I get a "could not find project file" errors for these files, if I add them. Is it possible that I don't have a complete mono installation? Thanks again for helping me with this...

Comment: I'm not even sure if Mono ships them. Or a C+ + compiler, for that matter.