# No build failure in TeamCity

Tags: c, visual-studio, teamcity

I'm running a TeamCity server on a Linux Ubuntu. These are my build settings when I add a project:

[image: Build Step: MSBuild]

When I build a simple C script from Visual Studio like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");

}
```

and I delete the last brace, what gives an error in Visual Studio, TeamCity is still saying it was build with succes.
All my failure conditions are checked:

[image: Common failure conditions]

Is there any other option that can be changed, so I get an appropriate error?

Comment: Have you checked the build logs?

Comment: [Step 1/1] HelloWorld.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build
[HelloWorld.sln.teamcity] /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld.sln Ignoring vcproj 'HelloWorld'.
[HelloWorld.sln.teamcity] /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld.sln Don't know how to handle GlobalSection SubversionScc, Ignoring.
[HelloWorld.sln.teamcity] /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld.sln Failed to find project c38426d5-0d39-4143-8e78-394e644dd1ef
[Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0

Comment: This is my build log: maybe the problem is in [HelloWorld.sln.teamcity] /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld.sln Failed to find project c38426d5-0d39-4143-8e78-394e644dd1ef ?

Comment: Yes, it probably is. Are the some files missing in source control? You can also have a look in the file system in the `/opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/` path to see what was checked out.

Comment: I don't see any files missing?

Answer (score 1):

When xbuild does not find a project which is part of the solution file, it will apparently emit a warning, not an error, which is why TeamCity does not mark the build as failed.

Check out the `/opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/` folder to see what files were checked out. Verify the path information in the solution file (e.g. is should have no absolute paths) and that the project file exists.

In the solution file, you should have an entry like that:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "HelloWorld", "path-to-vcproj-file", "{c38426d5-0d39-4143-8e78-394e644dd1ef}"
EndProject
```

The first GUID is the project type, the other GUID is the project ID.

Comment: In the file is the entry like you said above. The only difference is I have a .vcxproj instead of a .vcproj

Comment: Is the path correct? Are the GUIDs consistent (including upper/lower-case)?

Comment: Yes, the path is HelloWorld\HelloWorld.vcxproj

Comment: Does it work when you specify `HelloWorld\HelloWorld.vcxproj` as project file in TeamCity instead of the `sln` file?

Comment: No, I get this error: Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to detect default target(s) in the project file /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.vcxproj. Please define targets explicitly in the build configuration options on TeamCity Web UI. Document element did not appear. file:///opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.vcxproj Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Is the file `/opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8‌​427/HelloWorld/Hello‌​World.vcxproj` empty or not readable (permission-wise) by the TeamCity Agent?

Comment: I can go to the file with nano and read it, so I think it's not permission-wise?

Comment: Well, the error "Document element did not appear. [...] Line 1, position 1" most likely indicates an empty XML file, so I'd search in that direction; the build agent may run with other privileges than you do. Nevertheless, the answer to "no build failure" is really that XBuild does only report warnings and not errors in this specific case.

Comment: When I compile the .vcxproj with xbuild, I get this error: HelloWorld.vcxproj: error : /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.vcxproj: /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/d4407e37ceba8427/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.vcxproj could not import "$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"

Comment: These files are apparently not part of the Mono XBuild installation, you probably need to copy the targets from your dev machine. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134766/defining-a-target-when-compiling-a-visual-c-project-using-xbuild

Comment: I can't find the targets only on a Windows, but not on a Linux. You have an idea of the path of the targets?

Comment: No, I don't know more than what is written in the post I linked to. Maybe open a new question asking specifically about building your vcxproj on linux using xbuild?